# Linux - Delete last two files automatically

Tags: files, scripting

In Linux, one folder is created every morning and 5 files are created in that folder.

At the end of the day (Midnight), the last two files in that folder have to be deleted. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: love to help give us more information. Is it a new folder each day if so what is the filename pattern. Same question for the files that need to be deleted. What have you tried so far?

Comment: With folder do you mean directory? What determines what the 'last two' files are? The order of creation? Please give the name and setup of some real life software that needs this (so we can give better feedback, and so we don't get the impression of doing your homework assignment for you).

Comment: use the rm command.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more information you could use this command to select the last 2 files in that directory and delete them. This assumes you want the last 2 files that were modified, deleted.

```
$ ls -t | head -n 2 | xargs rm -f
```

#### Example

Say I have these files.

```
$ seq 5 | xargs -n 1 touch
$ ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 3
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 5
```

Using `ls -t | head -n 2` would give me the last 2 modified files.

```
$ ls -t | head -n 2
5
4
```

And I can pass those to `xargs rm -f` to delete them.

```
$ ls -t | head -n 2 | xargs rm -f
$ ls -tr
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jun  5 04:01 3
```

Comment: Why would you reverse the list (`-r`) and use `tail` instead of using `head`? Note that it assumes file names don't contain space, tab, newline, single quote, double quote or backslash characters and don't start with `-`. Also note that `-1` is superfluous as `ls` only outputs on multiple columns if its output goes to a terminal. The `tail -2` syntax is deprecated. Use `tail -n 2` instead. Also note that `ls -t` sorts by last modification time, not creation time and omits hidden files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I reversed it so that the solution corresponded w/ how the OP envisioned solving the problem, i.e. removing the last 2 most recently added/modified files. I've fixed the `tail -n 2` and `ls -1` I've fixed. Changed text to say "modified" instead of "created". W/o more info from OP this was an approximation of a solution.

Comment: What I meant is that `ls -t | head -n 2` is the same as `ls -rt | tail -n 2`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - OK, changed those too.

Answer (score 2):

With zsh

```
rm -f -- *(D.om[1,2])
```

would delete (up to) the two newest (in terms of last modification time) regular files in the current directory.

With GNU tools:

```
eval "files=($(ls -At --quoting-style=shell-always))"
n=2
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  if [[ -f $f && ! -L $f ]]; then
    rm -f -- "$f"
    ((--n)) || break
  fi
done
```

Comment: is `zsh` going to be default shell in upcoming server OS ?

Comment: Yes, one day, zsh will rule the world. For now though, no major Unices beside OS/X (it even used to be the system shell there) include it in their default base installation. That's probably the only reason why you might want to use any other shell ;-)